# openerp 7: refresh / update form's related field after editing the related record via edit button

Tags: odoo

How do I refresh form's related field after edit the related record via edit button

When I edit a related record (many2one):

1. press the edit button and the popup windows appears.
2. I edit the related record, and press save to close the popup window.

**3. the form is updating it's many2one fields, but not it's related field as shown in my screen capture:**

[image]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  it seems like a bug.alternative for the moment is to select same record again.